# How to use Markdown with MathJax like Math StackExchange

Tags: javascript, markdown, mathjax

**UPDATED POST**

Ok I've managed to make Markdown and MathJax work together, it was relatively simple actually. I've used [`marked`](https://github.com/chjj/marked) together with MathJax.

```
$(function() {
    var $text       = $("#text"), // the markdown textarea
        $preview    = $("#preview"); // the preview div

    $text.on("keyup", function() {
        $preview.html( marked($text.val()) ); // parse markdown
        MathJax.Hub.Queue(["Typeset", MathJax.Hub, "preview"]); // then let MathJax do its job
    })
});
```

Problem now is: I think markdown is parsing my math 1st before MathJax can change it. How do i fix this? I think its fixed on Math StackOverflow, but how? I need to stop markdown from parsing math

**UPDATE 2**

This works, but not sure if its the way math.stackexchange does it, but it seems to produce similar/same results with what I tested so far ...

```
$(function() {
    var $text       = $("#text"),
        $preview    = $("#preview");

    $text.on("keyup", function() {
        $preview.html( $text.val() );
        MathJax.Hub.Queue(["Typeset", MathJax.Hub, "preview"]);
    });

    MathJax.Hub.Register.MessageHook("End Process", function (message) {
        $preview.html( marked($preview.html()) );
    });
});
```

---

**OLD POST BELOW**

In the math stackexchange, I can use MathJax with Markdown. I wonder what do I need to do that? I can use a library like `marked` to render Markdown, but for MathJax, it seems like it just renders on page loads. How can I call it to re-render or better just render whats needed (specified by me)

```
html = marked("some markdown string") // a HTML string
// is there something like
html = MathJax.parse(html)
```

---

**UPDATE**

I think I should be looking at http://www.mathjax.org/docs/1.1/typeset.html#manipulating-individual-math-elements. But when I try

```
$text.on("keyup", function() {
    $preview.html( marked($text.val()) );
    var math = MathJax.Hub.getAllJax("preview");
    console.log(math);
    MathJax.Hub.Queue(["Text", math, "a+b"]);
})
```

Where:

- `$text`: is the jQuery element for my textarea
- `$preview`: is the preview `div`

I find that `math` is undefined, so it seems `var math = MathJax.Hub.getAllJax("preview")` is not working. I have a `div#preview` btw.

Comment: Doing MathJax before markdown is clever (markdown passes html through) but means that math will be rendered *everywhere*. For example it's unclear that you want it rendered in `literal` text.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [let PageDown and MathJax work together](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11228558/let-pagedown-and-mathjax-work-together)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The fastest way is to protect the math from your markdown-parser.

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11228558/let-pagedown-and-mathjax-work-together/11231030#11231030) for a detailed answer by Davide Cervone, including a link to the code used by math.SE.

Answer (score 0):

For sublime, add the following code to `Markdown Preview --> Settings - User`,

```
{
    /*
        Enable or not mathjax support.
    */
    "enable_mathjax": true
}
```

as shown below,

[image]

Refer to [How to enable MathJax rendering in Sublimetext Markdown Preview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27972177/how-to-enable-mathjax-rendering-in-sublimetext-markdown-preview).