# MathJax in Pancake is different from that in Math.SE?

Tags: mathjax

```
$$\begin{align*}a_1=\alpha _1+\alpha _2+\cdots+\alpha _n,a_2=\alpha _1\alpha _2+\alpha _1\alpha _3+\cdots+\alpha _{n-1}\alpha _n,\cdots a_1 \end{align*}$$
```

#### Delete a_1 in the above, then that could be shown well.

```
$$\begin{align*}a_1=\alpha _1+\alpha _2+\cdots+\alpha _n,a_2=\alpha _1\alpha _2+\alpha _1\alpha _3+\cdots+\alpha _{n-1}\alpha _n,\cdots \end{align*}$$
```

http://hypergroups.pancakeapps.com/Test/test.txt

Of course they can show well in Math.SE

$$\begin{align*}a_1=\alpha _1+\alpha _2+\cdots+\alpha _n,a_2=\alpha _1\alpha _2+\alpha _1\alpha _3+\cdots+\alpha _{n-1}\alpha _n,\cdots a_1 \end{align*}$$

$$\begin{align*}a_1=\alpha _1+\alpha _2+\cdots+\alpha _n,a_2=\alpha _1\alpha _2+\alpha _1\alpha _3+\cdots+\alpha _{n-1}\alpha _n,\cdots \end{align*}$$

---

The MathJax here and Pancake are not the same?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look into the HTML source, you'll notice `<em>` tags within the equation I'm guessing from a Markdown conversion. MathJax's TeX parser stops at HTML tags (and skips incomplete equations).

You need to prevent the Markdown parser from messing up the TeX code. That's not trivial but there are many solutions out there; see for example [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11228558/let-pagedown-and-mathjax-work-together/11231030#11231030) from MathJax's lead developer.